# Having multiple users login at the same time during ui automation test case

Tags: oop, automation, ui-automation

I have been doing web automation since last year and am interested in knowing more about parallel testing. I am not looking for a coding solution but instead if someone could point me to some material that would cover this or simply a walkthrough steps on what I should be focusing on. Say I have a csv file with 15 users and all can have the same password.

1. Use a read function to read the file and store the usernames in an array
2. Perform a shuffle on the array
3. Choose the first index????
   #this will give you a single random value but I am yet to wrap my head around how the login function would be written to grab say 10 different usernames at the same time. Maybe I am looking at it all wrong.

How would I approach looping through that array and picking each user at random to send to the username textbox? Is there a random function available that chooses items at random without selecting the same item twice?

I have searched but I don't think I am knowledgeable enough to know what I am really searching for...

Don't bash me :-(

***The language is Python***